# Build process wants to install to GAC - but I lack permissions

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build-process

I have a rather large solution consisting of several projects that wants to install to GAC. But Visual Studio do not have permission to do this when running the build. I can do it if Visual Studio is started as administrator. Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your build process shouldn't be installing anything to the GAC. Instead, your build process should produce binaries and/or an installer, and the installer (or a simple script) should be the one installing assemblies into the GAC.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I didn't produce the original code, so the best solution would be a complete overhaul of the build process. But I think the developer made it for faster debugging.